# Python requests: Anyway to download just the body of a get response?

Tags: python, python-requests

So I first use requests.head() to download the header. I do some validation(check the status code, check content-type) if that is good I download the body. However I use requests.get() to that, but using .get() not only downloads the body but also the header which I just downloaded. So I don't need to download the header twice, anyway I can download the body of a get response if the header looks good?

Comment: You can't! This is not the way `HTTP` works.

Comment: What kind of validation are you doing? You should include more details about your actual usage. Perhaps in a new question though, as this is an okay question on it's own. Better to leave it and ask a new one about your actual usage.

Comment: That's not how range requests work; they let you get a range of bytes from the body. The header comes anyway.

Comment: Why do you need to pre-check for a `404` or `302`? How large is a typical body?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way. HTTP has the HEAD request, which only gets the header, but there's no request to get only the body.

Don't worry too much about efficiency until you need to; the header usually isn't too big anyway. Either use `requests.get()` in the first place if the body is small, or else do `requests.head()` followed by `requests.get()` if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't! This is not the way **HTTP** works. If you want to use less traffic you are in the right track all you need is to perform the `head` requests then check if you wanna get the body. If so use `get`.

Downloading the **HTTP headers** twice will not will not cost you (a lot) in performance or traffic and it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ask only the header in case of a 404 or 302 is non sense. Either you get the error and the cost is the same as directly asking the body, or you get no error and need a second request for the body.

So unless the body is really large I would directly ask for the body with a single request. And if it is large, but tranferred in chunked mode, you can read the header with the first chunk and abort the transfert if it has a wrong content-type.

HTTP `HEAD` request do not have common usages, and what you describe does not really looks like one. They are normally only used when you only need the header and will never use the body.

Comment: @user5226247: No, a 404 or 302 response will not contain the half megabyte (how could it for a *not found* code?). Just use a network spy like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to see it: those response uses less than 1k byte. To enable chunked mode, you must use HTTP 1.1 in your request, but the server is free to use it or not: some will other won't.